# The lore of the game Numenera mentions "an irrational number that may be a four-dimensional equivalent of $\pi$". What could this mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, pi

There's an RPG (Role-Playing Game) called [Numenera](http://numenera.com), set on the Earth a billion years in the future, which is covered in the partially-functional and generally weird and mysterious technological ruins of a billion years of advanced civilizations. In one of its sourcebooks, it lists possible fragmentary transmissions that a player character might receive from its global "datasphere", one of which is listed as the following:

> An irrational number that may be a four-dimensional equivalent of $\pi$.

When I saw this, my first thought was "I'm pretty sure that's probably just pi multiplied by a constant", followed by "If it's not, I'm sure mathematicians have already worked it out." When I did I Google search, I couldn't find anything obvious.

> So, what is the equivalent to pi for a four-dimensional hypersphere?

Comment: For dumbs like me, I have been obliged to google search in order to understand that RPG=Role Playing Game.

Comment: For the record, every number is just pi multiplied by some constant

Comment: @Carmeister I guess by "constant" he meant a rational number.

Comment: @JeanMarie The dumb thing is to used an abbreviation the reader won't understand

Comment: @David I figured that anyone who posted here was probably nerdy enough to know what an RPG was, but I've editted the question to include the elaboration of the acronym.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[You're close](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#The_volume).  The "volume" of a $4$-dimensional ball is given by
$$
V = \frac{\pi^2}{2}R^4
$$
and its "surface area" is given by
$$
S = 2 \pi^2 R^3.
$$
If we take the $n$-dimensional equivalent of $\pi$ to be the ratio between the volume of the $n$-ball and $R^n$ (the volume the $n$-cube with side length $R$), then the 4-D equivalent of $\pi$ is $\frac{\pi^2}{2}$.

More generally, we would have (for positive integers $k$)
$$
\begin{align}\pi_{2k} &= \frac{\pi^k}{k!}, \\
\pi_{2k+1} &= \frac{2^{k+1}\pi^k}{(2k+1)!!} = \frac{2(k!)(4\pi)^k}{(2k+1)!}.\end{align}
$$
where $\pi_n$ is the $n$-dimensional equivalent of $\pi$.  Because $\pi$ is known to be transcendental, we can conclude that these are all irrational (and transcendental as well).

Comment: A very rational way to obtain irrational numbers...

Comment: Note that the “surface area” is the derivative (wrt R) of the “volume”.

Comment: @Dan - only for highly symmetric shapes like the n-sphere and n-cube. It doesn't even work for ellipses.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Wow, I didn't know that it doesn't work for ellipses.

Comment: @BigbearZzz - that is why there is a nice simple formula for the area of an ellipse ($\pi ab$), but the circumference is given in terms of an Elliptic Integral for which no simple closed form exists.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I knew about these facts but never put them together before. I mistakenly believed that the "taking derivative of volume to get surface area" works for convex bodies with smooth boundary. Is there a simple criterion to check when does the method work?

Comment: @BigbearZzz - the effect of scaling up by some ratio needs to increase radial distances by the same amount in all directions. For the circle and the square, this is true. For the ellipse, and even non-square rectangles, this is false.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I see. Actually, if I think more carefully then I should've seen this fact but I just never paid much attention to it. Thank you for bringing this up, I now have one less misconception.

Comment: @BigbearZzz - I learned it the hard way, myself.

Answer (score 8):

If you mean the sphere in the 4-dimensional Euclidean space, then the ratio between its surface area and its radius cubed is $2\pi^2$

Comment: The ratio between surface area and radius squared is $4 \pi$ is 3-dimensional Euclidean space.  In $4$-dimensional space, the ratio between the "surface area" and the radius **cubed** is is $2 \pi^2$.

Comment: You're right! Edited

Comment: Of course, $\pi=4\pi/4$, thus one might argue that the 4D-equivalent of $\pi$ is $\pi^2/2$.

Comment: Well in this case the 4 dimensional analogous of $\pi$ would be, as the classical case of the circle, the ratio between the surface area of the 3-sphere (which has radius one) and its diameter cubed, thus $\frac{2\pi^2}{8}=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$

Answer (score 3):

Another possible generalization, that extends the "circumference to diameter" concept more directly, is to consider the *ratio of the surface volume to the volume of a diametric cross-section*, the latter of which is a sphere. In three dimensions, the equivalent is the ratio of surface area of the sphere to the area of a planar cross-section taken through the center (which is a circle), and to see the relationship to the two-dimensional case, note that "circumference" can be thought of as the "surface length" and "diameter" as the length of a linear cross-section through the center.

That is, in effect, the "$\pi$" is the ratio of the surface volume of a 4D ball of radius $R$ to the regular volume of a 3D ball of radius $R$. Thus...

The surface volume of the 4-dimensional ball is

$$\mathrm{SV} = 2\pi^2 R^3$$

and the volume of the 3-dimensional ball is

$$V = \frac{4}{3} \pi R^3$$

so the ratio is just

$$\pi_4 = \frac{\mathrm{SV}}{V} = \frac{2\pi^2 R^3}{\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3} = \frac{3}{2} \pi$$

Hence, "four-dimensional pi" is $\frac{3}{2} \pi$. You're welcome. And yes, it is $\pi$ times a constant (rational number, as @rghome mentions in the comments).

Comment: Interestingly, by this logic "three-dimensional pi" is
$$
\pi_3 = \frac{SA}{A} = \frac{4 \pi R^2}{\pi R^2} = 4.
$$
More generally, we get a rational pi in odd-dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Define $\pi$ as the unique real number such that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi x^2}\,\mathrm dx=1.$$
This is the same in $1,2,3,4,\dots$ dimensions.

Indeed, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi (x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2)}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dw=1.$